Why does the ordering of WhenEvent matter in NDSolve?
Note, I am changing the order of
WhenEvent[t < 15, u[t] -> 1],
WhenEvent[t >= 15, u[t] -> 0]

in the following code, which will give two different solutions:
ClearAll[alphacharge, u, x, alphadischarge, t]

alphadischarge = 1;

sol = NDSolve[{
   p'[t] == u[t] - alphadischarge*p[t],
   p[0] == 0,
   u[0] == 1,
   WhenEvent[t < 15, u[t] -> 1],
   WhenEvent[t >= 15, u[t] -> 0]
   },
  {p, u},
  {t, 0, 30}, DiscreteVariables -> {u}]

Plot[p[t] /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]


ClearAll[alphacharge, u, x, alphadischarge, t]

alphadischarge = 1;

sol = NDSolve[{
   p'[t] == u[t] - alphadischarge*p[t],
   p[0] == 0,
   u[0] == 1,
   WhenEvent[t >= 15, u[t] -> 0],
   WhenEvent[t < 15, u[t] -> 1]
   },
  {p, u},
  {t, 0, 30}, DiscreteVariables -> {u}]


What is the best way to avoid this problem? Can I wrap everything into one WhenEvent?

You are dealing with numerical issues.
I tried all the tricks in possible issues under WhenEvent help page, but non-worked. Looked under Event Detection section. They give number of option to improve detection. I tried them all, but none worked.
It seems to have detected t=15 numerically, so it picked the first event which matches. So when you changed the order this made the difference. It will not use the second event again, since it already detected t=15. This is what I think happened.
But I found if you change
WhenEvent[t < 15] 

to
WhenEvent[t < 15 - 5*$MachineEpsilon]

Then now changing the order of events gives same output.
ClearAll[alphacharge, u, x, alphadischarge, t]
alphadischarge = 1;
ode = {p'[t] == u[t] - alphadischarge*p[t], p[0] == 0};
ic = {p[0] == 0, u[0] == 1};
when1 = WhenEvent[t < 15 - 5*$MachineEpsilon, u[t] -> 1];
when2 = WhenEvent[t >= 15, u[t] -> 0];
when = {when1, when2};
sol = NDSolve[{ode, ic, when}, {p, u}, {t, 0, 30}, 
  DiscreteVariables -> {u}]
Plot[p[t] /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]


Now we change the order, and get same output
when={when2,when1};
sol=NDSolve[{ode,ic,when},{p,u},{t,0,30},DiscreteVariables->{u}]

Plot[p[t]/. sol[[1]],{t,0,30},PlotRange->All]



You actually need only one single When-event. You want to change u at t==15. Therefore, it is unnecessary overkill to specify When-events at every point:
sol = NDSolve[{p'[t] == u[t] - alphadischarge*p[t], p[0] == 0, 
   u[0] == 1, WhenEvent[t == 15, u[t] -> 0]}, {p, u}, {t, 0, 30}, 
  DiscreteVariables -> {u}]

Plot[{p[t], u[t]} /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]


